# Checking if pairs from zip are correct?

Tags: python, list

I need your advice on this problem.

I have collected what I need in these two lists: `simpl2`, `astik`, with this code:

```
simpl2 = [] 
astik = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    for name in files:
        if 'sim2.shp' == name:
            simpl2.append(os.path.join(path, name))
        elif 'ASTIK.shp' == name:
            astik.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

The code above searches in a rootfolder that contains folders: `v1.v2,v3,v4`
So using this:

```
for i,j in zip(simpl2,astik): 
    print(i,j)
```

gives this:

**CONTENT**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl\v1\exported\sim2.shp C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl\v1\ASTIK\ASTIK.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl\v2\exported\sim2.shp C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl\v4\ASTIK\ASTIK.shp
```

**Question**

How to ensure that the pairs would be from the same folder (like the first row that come both from `v1` and if don't (like the second row where one is from `v2` and the other from `v4`) make them not have a pair at all.

This should happen because, they will be used later and they have to be correct pairs otherwise I have a code ready with exception for those that don't have a pair, so the problem is how to fix this part that is described earlier.

**Explanation**

The rootfolder is:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl
```

after that `pl` there is a v1,v2,v3,v4 folder. Each of these folders has some files that are the same to all the 4 folders. The only difference is that some will be empty. I just want to check if correct pairs of the same `v` are created in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seeing your update maybe you are interested in something more like this:

```
import os

simpl2 = []
astik = []

rootfolder = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pl'
subfolders = [os.path.join(rootfolder, i) for i in ['v1','v2','v3','v4']]

for folder in subfolders:

    temp = {name: os.path.join(path, name) 
            for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder)
            for name in files
            if name in ['sim2.shp', 'ASTIK.shp']}

    if len(temp) == 2:
        simpl2.append(temp['sim2.shp'])
        astik.append(temp['ASTIK.shp'])
```

---

**OLD CODE**

**But...** if this is your end goal you could also just store the paths. If both files are in the path then you know the path contains both files. You can then easily build the endpaths with os.path.join() when needed.

```
paths = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    if ('sim2.shp' in files) and ('ASTIK.shp' in files):
        paths.append(path)
```

Or a more compact format:

```
lookfor = ['sim2.shp','ASTIK.shp']
paths = [p for p,s,f in os.walk(rootfolder) if all(i in f for i in lookfor)]
```

Comment: The files are not in the same subfolder. If you can see under the 'content' in the question the files should be searched by the [-3] position which is the `v1` for example. Your first piece of code doesn't store anything although the `v1` has both `sim2` and `ASTIK`. Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: @user10319541 That is strange indeed. But try to elaborate in your question with an easy example where the files are to be found.

Comment: Watch under the 'CONTENT' where the files are listed to see. The check should be done by the [-3] location of the path. In the place of the `v` either v1,v2,v3,v4 inside each of those folders are the subfolders of all the files under investigation.

Comment: @user10319541 Ok I see now. How about you store all the subfolders first to an array. And then you loop all those subfolders and find your pair among the items?

Comment: I added a few more details at last part of the question to clarify more.

Comment: @user10319541 Need to answer a call. Will be back if nobody else answers.

Comment: It doesn't store anything.

Comment: @user10319541 Try use print statements and understand what is going wrong. Works for me.